# WP_Head not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, header, nextgen-gallery

[wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) function is not working from few days. Jquery not loading on main site now, and nextgen gallery also not detecting this function, but this function currently present in my header file.

I've tried re-installation of wordpress, nextgen gallery, and theme. Is there any way to solve this problem without re-installation of website.

Comment: It's `wp_head()` all small caps.

Comment: yeah i know, i just highlighted it in this que.

Comment: Have you tried removing `<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` just after your `wp_head()` call?

Comment: nope.. still showing wp_head missing in nextgen gallery

Comment: hey.. its worked.. means my effects are working but they work only when the whole site loaded, if i click on any image on loading time , it opened without jquery. how can i solve this problem now

Comment: The issue also might happen, if you accidentally called 'wp_head' hook with other function, inside it's own(current) call back.(facepalm). Might help some great people like me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding more than one jquery version that can be causing conflicts. can you add the no conflict js?

Comment: jquery is not the problem, it was working from 2 months ago, till last week.. and i dont know php, so please make an easier answer.

Comment: you was right... and there was lots of versions of jquery in my site.. thats why it was not working.. now its  working. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had a look in your `header.php`, there are a couple of issues:

**1. [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)**

You didn't use it like recommended. It should be in your `functions.php`. Here's an example from the Codex:

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('scriptaculous');            
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method'); // For use on the Front end (ie. Theme)
?>
```

**2. Placement of [wp_head()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head)**

It is recommended to use `wp_head()` just before your `</head>` tag.

**3. Including jQuery 1.4.4**

Check your console for errors and also check that your gallery plugin supports the current version of jQuery you are using. And it also "clashes" with the above `wp_enqueue_script("jquery")` you used. Load your page and view the source to see the actual files being included by `wp_head()` and the `get_theme_option("head")`.

Comment: thanq for you answer sir, but, i tried same theme, same gallery plugin with my other blog, and it worked. here is something else.. and yeah i tried to put wp_head() right before </head> but its not worked and sorry , because of "i dont know php" i did'nt get ur 1 and 3 suggestion.

Comment: Install `Firebug Add-on` on Firefox, and hit the `F12` key on your keyboard. A little window will appear and it will have a tab called `Console`. All javascript errors will be found there.

Comment: ok leave it.. i'll see this problem... soon. if you can solve my another problem, please..

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue while developing project.

In my issue, I need to add custom style from the plugin to add into the head.

```
function custom_style(){
    ?>
    <style>
    .search_page_outer_wrapper{
        background:red;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head','custom_style');
```

So after tried lots of solution, I have found a solution.

**1) Add wp_head hook function above the "get_header()" function. Like this :**

```
<?php


function custom_style(){
    ?>
    <style>
    .search_page_outer_wrapper{
        background:red;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head','custom_style');

get_header();
```

**2) Second solution : Check wp_head() added in header.php or not if not then please add that**